# insert non-overlapping range in 2 column table

Tags: java, javascript, sql, algorithm

I have a database table with 2 columns.

```
+-------+-------+
|min    |max    |
+-------+-------+
|0      |99,999 |
+-------+-------+
|100000 |499999 |
+-------+-------+
|1000000|9999999|
+-------+-------+
```

I need to implement a logic which will allow only non overlapping `range(min,max)` to be entered. For example 5,500000 should not be allowed but 500000,900000 should be allowed.

The logic can be implemented in `JAVA`, `SQL`, or `JS`.

Comment: And you tried like... nothing? At all? `"I need to implement a logic"` - that's nice of you to say! But is there any question, or are you simply looking for a naive worker to do it?

Comment: As a side note, `max` should be stored as an exclusive value - that is the first row should be `0 | 100,000`, the second `100,000 | 500,000`, etc.  Especially if you're querying anything that isn't an integer count, this makes the range query safe (rather than loosing random values).  If you only had existing contiguous ranges (and are backed by a db with certain features), this actually allows the upper bounds to be _derived_.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example: http://jsfiddle.net/6QFRV/1/

```
function isAllowed(number)
{
    var ranges = [
        {min: 0, max: 100},
        {min: 150, max: 250},
        {min: 251, max: 300}
    ];

    for (key in ranges)
    {
        var range = ranges[key];
        if (number >= range.min && number <= range.max)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

alert(isAllowed(10)); //true
alert(isAllowed(101)); //false
alert(isAllowed(299)); //true
```

Comment: i dont think that this is the solution. He is speakin about input ranges.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the question is for ranges, not for detecting single point inclusion.  However it's simply an elaboration of that because range(min,max) should return true if and only if both min and max are not included -- you simply have to test both points OR alternately if one of the a range in the database endpoints is contained within range(min.max).  It's also not necessary to loop over everything.  You should be able to use the databases ability to find the end points quickly.  Assuming there are indexes on the min and max columns, then the order of algorithm would be O(log N) where N is the number of rows in the database as opposed to O(N) if you search every row.

Assuming range(min,max) results in 2 variables range_min and range_max, I think you can do something like

```
select count(*) from min_max_table mmt where
   range_min > mmt.min and range_min < mmt.max or
   range_max > mmt.min and range_max < mmt.max or
   mmt.min > range_min and mmt.min < range_max or
   mmt.max > range_min and mmt.max < range_max
   limit 1;
```

if the result of this select is 0 then allowed is true, otherwise is false.